# Codeigniter base_url() config not changing

Tags: codeigniter-3, virtualhost, wampserver

On a WAMP Virtual Host site I am using codeigniter's base_url to load content.

I have changed the file in the config (application/config/config.php)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
```

I have loaded the url helper in the autoload.php file. (application/config/autoload.php)

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

And on my files I have the following to access the base url:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>img/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" height="150" width="150">
```

But the SRC address I am getting is (and the browser obviously doesn't find the resource):

```
http://[::1]/img/Logo.jpg
```

When I should be getting:

```
http://example.com/img/Logo.jpg
```

So, why isn't my codeigniter chaning the base_url()? Am I missing something?

EDIT: This is the configuration code for the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/example/"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/example/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possible that you're overwriting the value of `$config['base_url']` somewhere.

Comment: make sure path of project to VH is correct

Comment: The VH path is correct because I can load the pages themselves, it's the references to images, JS, CSS that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Could you provide the htaccess content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the codeigniter configuration I had was tampered with. The code in system/core/Config.php

It was overriden by someone else. Completely different problem. Replaced the file with the one codeigniter originally provides and it works.

Your core config file should look like this:

https://github.com/scotch-io/Github-API-Library-For-CodeIgniter/blob/master/system/core/Config.php